# WordPress default search and Woocommerce product search

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem when trying to get the search to work for both the default WordPress blog search and WooCommerce product search and I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. What I have in functions.php right now is:

```
function wp_search_filter($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    }
    if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) : 
        if ( $query->is_search && is_woocommerce() ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
        }
    endif;
    return $query;
 }
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wp_search_filter');
```

But my product search does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work" - that tells us nothing. Are you getting an error? is it not returning any results/all results/the wrong results? Is the search just dying?

Comment: It does not display any results. It shows the 'no posts found' message. WordPress blog search works fine but the product search just won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, in case anyone needs a solution, I just came up with something that works. The problem here was that the is_woocommerce() condition is not firing on search results template. To get around that I used this code:

```
function wp_search_filter($query) {
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( (strpos($url,'post_type=product') !== false) && is_search() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','wp_search_filter');
```